# How to use isVisible/isElementPresent in angularjs e2e testing, throwing error " TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isVisible'"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angular-resource, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to verify that an elemnt is present or not. I was using isVisible but it throws error message "TypeError: Object # has no method 'isVisible'"

```
it('should verify all the elements present',function(){
    expect(manageUser.manageUserTitle.getText()).toMatch('Manage Users');
    expect(manageUser.addUserButton.isElementPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userName.isVisible()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userEmail.isVisible()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userRole.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.lastLogin.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userAction.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userDelete.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    expect(manageUser.userEdit.isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

Anyone help from anyone. I am using page factory

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is .isDisplayed()

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebelementprototypeisdisplayed

Comment: Hey @rjferguson21 when i tried expect(personalSetting.changePasswordDialogBox.isDisplayed).toBe(true); then it is throwing error  'Expected Function to be true.' any idea i am writing it in incorrect manner?

Comment: @ZahidAfaque You are not actually invoking the 'isDisplayed' function.  Try changing it to this:    expect(personalSetting.changePasswordDialogBox.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

Comment: i tried this also but still same problem i am facing

Comment: Are you using a page object?  How are you selecting the element?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
    var resetPage = true;
    var counter = 0;

    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log("Test " + ++counter);
        if (resetPage) {
            //browser.get(helper.biometricSaveUrl);
            page.resetBtn.isDisplayed().then(function (visible) {
                if (visible)
                    page.resetBtn.click();
            });
        }
    });
```